# Can I make object unmutable once the constructor is called?

Tags: java, immutability

```
class X
{
  String x1;
  String x2;
  //...
  String x15;

  public X (Other o)
  {
    // initialize x1,x2,...,x15
  }

  String getx1 () { return x1; }  // lot of getters
  String getx2 () { return x2; }
  //...
  String getx15 () { return x15; }
}
```

The object of `class X` is initialized in constructor of `class Other`;

```
class Other
{
  private X obj;
  // Other members
  public Other ()
  {
    obj = new X(this);
    //...
  }
  //...
}
```

I want to somehow get rid of lot of `getter` methods in `class X`. I can simply remove those and make all the data members of `X` in `default` scope (`X` is used only within package).

Is there any way by which I can make the members of `X obj` un-mutable after the constructor `Other` is called ? Here the idea is, when using `get()` methods, the variables inside `X` cannot be modified.

```
obj.getx1();
```

Now, if I use simply `obj.x1` then there are chances that it might get overwritten (or at least in code review, it will be objected).

[Note: `obj` has to be initialized in the `Other()` constructor only].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to make a class immutable (not un-mutable) is to mark all fields as `final` (visibility is irrelevant, can be `public`). Fields must be initialized either with an initializer:

```
class A { final int x = 10; }
```

or in every constructor:

```
class A { 
   final int x, y, z;
   A(int x, int y, int z) { this.x = x;, this.y = y; this.z = z; }
   A() { this (0, 0, 0); }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you declare you member variables as `final`, then they are immutable after constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you make the class immutable:

```
class X {
  private final String x1;
  private final String x2;

  public X (Other o)
  {
    x1 = o.getX1();
    x2 = o.getX2();
  }

  String getX1 () { return x1; } 
  String getX2 () { return x2; }
}
```

However, getting rid of the getters is usually a bad idea.  For instance:

- Getters reduce coupling, and allow the actual implementation types of the `xn` fields to be changed without breaking client code.
- Getters can be overridden in a subclass but bare attributes can't.
- Getters allow the object to be used as a "Java bean".

And the presence or absence of getters doesn't make the class immutable.

Answer (score 1):

The getter methods don't make the instance mutable. That would be *setter* methods. Your `X`, as defined, is already immutable — nothing can change the `x` values of an instance, they can only be *retrieved* via the getters.

If you're asking how to get rid of the getter methods and allow direct access to the member variables: Any decent JVM will inline those getter functions via its JIT compiler, making them direct member retrievals instead. So if you keep the getters, you keep flexibility for changes down-the-line, at very nearly no cost.

Comment: It might even be a good idea to declare the String instances as final as they never change. This is particularly a good idea if your object instances will be thrown back and forth between different threads.

Comment: I have edited my question. Actually, I want to get rid of `getters` and also to avoid getting `x1,x2` overwritten while using as `obj.x1`